# objective C Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_secTrustEvaluate"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

I am try to check if the phone has a configuration profile is installed on an iPhone using [this](http://alex.tapmania.org/2011/09/check_conf_prof_is_installed_ios.html) tutorial

I encountered the following issue , when I wrote this line :

```
err = secTrustEvaluate (trust,&trustResult);
```

I get the following warning

```
implicit declaration of function 'secTrustEvaluate' is invalid in C99
```

and I get the following erros when I try to build

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_secTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
      -[<Class name> <function name>] in <class object.o>
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also included the Security.framework Framework (which removed several issues similar to this one)

any reason why this is not working ?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a typo - `secTrustEvaluate(...)` should be `SecTrustEvaluate(...)`?

Comment: Thanks Paul. the code runs sucessfully now but when I run the program it crashes at the line `SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)certData);` 

I checked the code and noticed that there is no data in both `certPath` and `certData` . any idea why this is not happening ? I think I have a problem in setting the Target ( what should it be ?)

Comment: If you're unable to debug this using the normal methods then feel free to post another question, including the relevant code and exact details of where and how it crashes etc.